# black game object in unity instead of appearing in white color in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Black game object in unity instead of appearing in white color in unity and also showing a error with light.

Please let e know how to resolve it .

Comment: Fix the `error with light` ...

Answer (score 0):

Check the material on the object, is the material present? If it is, check to see if that material is lit or unlit.
I am assuming you have not doing anything with the lighting and have a default point light in your scene?